# Wordpress plugin for data transfer from contact form to Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: wordpress, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, contacts

What is the best Wordpress Plugin that automatically sends data from a contact form into the CRM Dynamics 365? Many thanks!

Comment: Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to take a look on plugin from AlexaCRM - https://docs.alexacrm.com/wpcrm/